# How do I push a Team Services git repository after build to an external git repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops

### Push to a different repository then the origin

I have a Team Services git repository which I successfully clone and build when releasing my project. After the build, I would like to push my build artifact to a different git repository location.

### git commands via the command line tasks

I'm able to initialize a git repo from the build artifact via a command line task (`git init`), but Team Service won't allow for fetching, pulling and pushing via the command line task.

### External git endpoint

So, the documentation says I need to use the [external git endpoint](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-tasks#external-git-service-endpoint). But I don't see how I can use this endpoint to push my build to.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick test with this but didn't see any issue. The git repository can be pushed to external remote repository successfully.

To reduce the steps in the definition, I created a batch script to perform the git action and upload the batch script into VSTS Source Control:

```
git init

git add .

git commit -m "VSTSBuildArtifacts"

git remote add origin https://xxxxxxxxx

git pull origin master

git push origin master
```

Following is my steps(I skipped the build steps, just copied some files as the build output files):

1. Create an empty build definition.
2. Add "Copy Files" task and configure it to copy some files to "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)" folder.
   [image]
3. Add a "Batch Script" task and set the "Path" to the batch script file and "Working folder" to "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)".
   [image]
4. Save the definition and queue a build.[image]

Comment: Hi Eddie! Thanks for the great answer! I'm basically doing the same thing. I think the `git pull` command needs authorization? It won't pull from the origin and times out eventually. You think that might be the case?

Comment: @Kriem That may be the case, I have included the authorization information when add the remote, so I didn't see any issue.

Comment: @Kriem Use this format: git pull https://username:password@mygithost.com/my/repository

Comment: You can also generate a PAT with access to the repository (Security Settings). Then format the URL as such:
`git push -u https://Personal%20Access%20Token:{myTokenHere}@{mySiteHere}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_git/{repository} master`